# Azure Devops Pipeline YAML - Dependencies Filtered Array In Conditional

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use the [filtered array syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#filtered-arrays) in a conditional for a stage

```
stages:
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo 'One' 

- stage: Two
  dependsOn: One
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo 'Two' 

- stage: Three
  dependsOn: One
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: throw

- stage: Four
  condition: containsValue(dependencies.*.result, 'Failed')
  dependsOn:
  - One
  - Two
  - Three
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo 'Four'
```

Based on my understanding of the filtered array syntax, this should access the 'result' property of all of the stage dependencies, and since stage Three always fails, the expression should be evaluate true. However, when I run the pipeline,
[stage 4 is still skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePYKb.png), and the only output given is 'The job was skipped'.

I have tried to debug to the best of my abilities but unfortunately you can't access the `dependencies` within job or step contexts (since in those contexts you use `stageDependencies`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try dumping all dependencies in a stage four variable using convertToJson(dependencies) and convertToJson(stageDependencies) and printing in console - that might give you a clue what values are present and what you are checking

For example:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    variables:
      myDependencies: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
    steps:
     - script: | 
        echo "dependencies- $(myDependencies)"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myAvar;isoutput=true]myval" 
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    - name: stage_stageDependencies
      value: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]
    - name: stage_dependencies
      value: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
     - script: | 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myBvar;isoutput=true]myBval" 
  - job: B2
    dependsOn: B1
    variables:
    - name: B2Job_dependencies
      value: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "stage_stageDependencies: $(stage_stageDependencies)"
        echo "stage_dependencies: $(stage_dependencies)"
        echo "B2Job_dependencies: $(B2Job_dependencies)"
```

**Note:** There are two objects stageDependencies and dependencies (for jobs). And they get populated if dependsOn are defined.

Comment: Could you provide the syntax? I tried multiple times to create a variable using convertToJson and always got empty output

Comment: hope the above example helps